# Google shortner issu

Tags: php, goo.gl

So i have a small PHP script to generate short links, it work but some times i got this error :

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id","file":ShortLink.php","line":31

**This is my script :**

```
<?php

class ShortLink {

public static function generateShortLink($longUrl)
{
    //This is the URL you want to shorten
    $apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
    //Get API key from : http://code.google.com/apis/console/

    $postData = array('longUrl' => $longUrl, 'key' => $apiKey);
    $jsonData = json_encode($postData);

    $curlObj = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url');
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

    $response = curl_exec($curlObj);

    //change the response json string to object
    $json = json_decode($response);

    curl_close($curlObj);

    return $json->id;
   }

 }
```

When i start worked with this script 6 or 7 months ago i hadn't this error but now i start get it and i have no idea why, so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

**Update :** 
When i `vardump` my `$json` i get that :

```
{ ["domain"]=> string(11) "usageLimits" ["reason"]=> string(26) "userRateLimitExceededUnreg" ["message"]=> string(40) "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up" ["extendedHelp"]=> string(36) "https://code.google.com/apis/console" } } ["code"]=> int(403) ["message"]=> string(40) "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up" }}
```

So i wondered if Google limited the Google shorten service ?

Comment: I try your code, and it is work for me.
Perhaps sometimes your internet connection is away or other temporary problems?

Comment: *User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up* You haven't signed up in Google API Console.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ShortLink { 
public static function generateShortLink($longUrl)
{
    //This is the URL you want to shorten
    $apiKey = 'YOUR_SERVER_API_KEY';
    //Get API key from : http://code.google.com/apis/console/

    $postData = array('longUrl' => $longUrl, 'key' => $apiKey);
    $jsonData = json_encode($postData);

    $curlObj = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url');
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

    $response = curl_exec($curlObj);

    //change the response json string to object
    $json = json_decode($response);

    curl_close($curlObj);
    if(!is_object($json))  
    {  
        return(false);  
    }  
    return $json->id;
   }

}
$api = new ShortLink();
$shorturlid=$api->generateShortLink('http://avecsrthgdgnb.avcd');
echo $shorturlid;
```

are you using new console then enable URL Shortener API.

Comment: i tried your code i had the same issue, i just want to know if i must sign up on google API console ?

Comment: $apiKey = 'YOUR_SERVER_API_KEY'; 
    yes signup and get API key from : http://code.google.com/apis/console/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes because of network curl is not returned with response within 30 seconds (default time limit in php for a cmd to finish)

Try changing the time limit in php.ini or if that is not in your control or you do not want to modify it for all the php cmds try `bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` before calling `curl_exec`

**Update:**

I see there is no id field in the json that is returned.

```
{ ["domain"]=> string(11) "usageLimits" 
  ["reason"]=> string(26) "userRateLimitExceededUnreg" 
  ["message"]=> string(40) "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up" 
  ["extendedHelp"]=> string(36) "https://code.google.com/apis/console" 
} 
}  
  ["code"]=> int(403) 
  ["message"]=> string(40) "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up" 
}
}
```

And if you closely see your User rate limit has been reached [See here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas#general_api) for details on limitation on using google apis. (You may try different IP i.e. different machine or different api key and same code may start working).

Hope this helps

Comment: No. Please refer to OP's JSON response.

Comment: Yes I saw that after I posted it